# convert string to char , space character was not converted correctly

Tags: c++, string, char

I use the code that allows me to convert any type (int, double, float, char) to string. I tested the program and choose `char` as type value.

```
stringstream ss;
    string s;
    char c = '3';
    ss << c;
    ss >> s;

    cout << "CHAR" << endl;
    bitset<8> bs2( (char) c );
    for( int i = (int) bs2.size(); i >= 0; i-- )
        cout << bs2[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    bitset<8> bs1( (char) s.c_str()[0]);
    cout << "STRING" << endl;
    for( int i = (int) bs1.size(); i >= 0; i-- )
        cout << bs1[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
```

The output is

```
CHAR
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
STRING
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

But I found one strange thing. I set `char c = ' '` and the value was not convert correctly.

```
CHAR
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
STRING
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I could not find explanation for it and what I did wrong.

Comment: Could it be that the extraction operator ignores whitespace?

Comment: hmmm, good question. than how can I convert any type to string and string to any type?? do you have some suggestion?

Comment: Also are you sure that is your real code? You should get an "index out of bounds" error for the `bitset`s because you are starting at `bs2.size()` which is out of bounds, instead of `bs2.size() - 1`

Comment: Well, did you notice your code is printing nine bits instead of eight? :)

Comment: While it may work, it isn't safe. `std::bitset::operator[]` does not perform bounds checking, however the behavior for indexing a value of of bounds is undefined. You can verify this by using `std::bitset::test()`, which does perform bounds checking. Also, you can look at your output and see that 9 digits are printed, which isn't correct for an array with 8 elements in it.

Comment: You both are right. But the bit output was just for check the value. But thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator>>` for `std::string` will only read until the first whitespace character encountered. If you want to extract all of the information in the `std::stringstream`, use the `str()` member function:

```
s = ss.str();
```

For reference see the description of [`operator>>(istream& s, string& str)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator%3E%3E/) and [`stringstream::str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/str/)

Comment: And what about if I would like to convert back? String to some type. I tried but it has the same affect.

Comment: I don't think there is a "universal" way to do this, `operator<<` and `operator>>` are not required to be symmetrical as you've already seen with `std::string`. You'll probably need to investigate this on a type-by-type basis. In the case of `char`, you can instruct the stream to not skip whitespace with the `std::noskipws` manipulator, something like: `ss >> std::noskipws >> c`.

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator won't return the space, use `ss.str();` to get the stringstream value.